# Can I add properties to a Mapping Table in postgres using Jakarta Persistence without creating a seperate entity?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following many to many relationship...

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_brand_access",
            schema = "auth",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="brand_id")
    )
    private Set<Brand> brands;
```

This works fine as long as the table just has those 2 properties and an autogenerated id column. However, they would now like to add a column for the userID of the person adding the record. Now when I try to add a record I get...

```
2023-01-25 16:56:53 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: record "new" has no field "created_by"
2023-01-25 16:56:53   Where: SQL statement "INSERT INTO logging.history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val,created_by)
2023-01-25 16:56:53                                 VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW),COALESCE(NEW.created_by,NEW.updated_by,'my-user'))"
```

I am assuming this is because I am not defining the created by. I could probably solve this by creating a separate "PersonBrand" entity but as I go down that rabbit hole the model gets fairly confusing. Is there a way I can add this value to the relationshp without having to create a whole other entity?

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming this is because I am not defining the created by. I could probably solve this by creating a separate `PersonBrand` entity but as I go down that rabbit hole the model gets fairly confusing.

This is absolutely the right and correct and normal and recommended thing to do and I don't see why it would be confusing.

Indeed, our usual recommendation for many years has been to avoid the use of `@ManyToMany` for precisely the reason you have discovered for yourself: that database tables with two FK columns *almost inevitably* get extra columns added to them at some point, and then you have to go and change your Java code.

Comment: What about the creation of a "Metadata" table that uses the mapping table's ID? That would still allow me to use many to many and also allow my to store extra data if I need to as well?

Comment: Also isn't this a pattern where a Graph would be more appropriate given you could add properties to vectors?